# Yas-snippets not showing dropdown suggestions for python(only)

Tags: yasnippet, doom

As the title says Yas snippets don't show a suggestion dropbox when in python mode.I can still tab complete the snippets(just no suggestions).
It works as expected in other modes(tried in latex,org and cpp),with a suggestion dropbox.
Any help is much appreciated.
Additional info:
I use Doom Emacs(minimally modified).